# Segmentation fault traversing a text file

Tags: c, gcc, segmentation-fault

I have this code, it's supposed to read a text file character by character and then do something with it, but the code keeps on segfaulting at line 6.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    printf("a\n");
    FILE* fp = fopen("~/pset5/dictionaries/small", "r");
    for (int a = fgetc(fp); a != EOF; a = fgetc(fp))
    {
        printf("b\n");        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Something weird is definitely happening, because it doesn't even print `"a\n"` to the terminal, even tough the call to `printf` is before the error. I've run the program with gdb, and this is where it fails.

```
6           for (int a = fgetc(fp); a != EOF; a = fgetc(fp))
(gdb) n

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
_IO_getc (fp=0x0) at getc.c:38
38      getc.c: No such file or directory.
```

I've also ran it with valgrind as in `valgrind --leak-check=full ./test`, with test being the name of the executable, and this is the relevant error message:

```
==7568== Invalid read of size 4
==7568==    at 0x4EA8A21: getc (getc.c:38)
==7568==    by 0x4005ED: main (test.c:6)
==7568==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==7568== 
==7568== 
==7568== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==7568==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
```

I'm really at a loss here, can someone explain what's going on with this segmentation fault, and why the hell isn't the first call to `printf` printing anything?

Comment: Did you check the return value of `fopen()`? Does not look like that.

Comment: What happens if you remove the for loop completely and execute from a commandline prompt (to keep outputs visible beyond end of program)? Is the first printf visible then? Then return the for loop and try again, same way.

Comment: @Yunnosch going to try that now.

Comment: @Yunnosch it works now, thank you! I commented out the for loop, recompiled, then uncommented out the for loop and recompiled and now it prints before the segmentation fault. No idea why it works now with this printf statement, but it does.

Comment: Remotely solving software bugs by magic, since 1839. Actually melmomene comments were targeting similar problems. Not uptodate, way of executing etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the debugger says (`fp=0x0`), you're calling `fgetc` with a null pointer. This is what causes the crash.

`fp` is null because the `fopen` call failed. You need to check for errors.

Opening the file fails because most likely you do not have a directory called `~`. Recall that expanding `~` to your home directory is done by the shell when you type a command. `fopen` only takes real filenames.

Comment: And why does the call to printf fail?

Comment: @chilliefiber How are you running this program?

Comment: @chilliefiber What makes you think that your failure is at printf and not in the looping?

Comment: @Yunnosch `"a\n"` is not printed.

Comment: Ah, the very first printf, ok. That was partially my misunderstanding. But you (OP) might want to refer to that printf in a more foolproof way. ;-)

Comment: @Yunnosch the failure is not at printf, however it doesn't actually print "a\n", and that is before the error and as such should be printed, as per my understanding.

Comment: @melpomene I'm running it as `./test` in the directory with the executable.

Comment: @chilliefiber I can't explain that. Output to a terminal should be line buffered by default. Are you sure `test` is up to date? What happens if you delete `./test`, recompile your code, and run it again?

Comment: Just to mention, in the question the printf reference is as foolproof as it can get.... :-)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to check the return value of `fopen()` against NULL, which indicates an error while attempting to open the file.

Your `for` loop busily uses a NULL pointer, hence you get segfault.

Check the global variable `errno` to find out more about what exactly went wrong in your case.